# Can I use multiple calendarID's with the google calendar api?

Tags: javascript, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I want to use the Google Calendar api with multiple calendar IDs. How can I get this working in the following code?

```js
function listUpcomingEvents() {
        gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'calenderID',
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 10,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        }).then(function(response) {
          var events = response.result.items;
          appendPre('Afspraken:');

          if (events.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
              var event = events[i];
              var when = event.start.dateTime;
              if (!when) {
                when = event.start.date;
              }
              appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('Geen afspraken vandaag');
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: What you are asking is way broader than an SO answer should be plus the task is very weakly defined. You can call `gapi.client.calendar.events.list` multiple times. If they belong to different Google Account identities, you need to take care of all authentication / authorisation steps as well. Collect results separately per calendar or mix and style then display them on whatever criteria that suits your needs.

Comment: @marekful This question is also quite clear and not broad in any sense of the word. 
 Also as a user can potentially have access to more than one calendar this question is valid and has nothing to do with authorization.  The response does calendar id so separating them would not have been that hard. If it works which it doesnt.

Answer (score 2):

The [events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) method has one primary parameter for the call that being calendar id

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events

Each call to this endpoint is for a single calendar id.  Its not possible to make single request to this endpoint or any of the other Google calendar api endpoints with multiple calendar ids.   You will need to make a request for each calendar you would like to retrieve data on.

Comment: The fact that it accepts an array makes it a bit confusing. Feature request?